# How to get resources directory path using java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, file-upload, cucumber

I am testing test in cucumber which i want to upload file from testData to S3 bucket:

```
String bucket = bucketname+ "/ADL";
String ActualFilesPathForComparison = Environment.getInstance().getValue(DATAINPUTPATH);
temp = ActualFilesPathForComparison+inputPath+ File.separator+ file;
s3.uploadFile(bucket, file, new File (temp)); 

public void uploadFile(String bucketName, String fileKeyName, File localFilePath) {
    try {
        this.s3.putObject((new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileKeyName, localFilePath)).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    } catch (Exception var5) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Upload file failed.", var5);
    }
}
```

I have this file:

```
src\main\resources\testData\testInputsFile\testLZInputUnZippedFiles\Log.csv
```

when i run the test i am getting from the debug:

```
localFilePath = testData\testInputsFile\testLZInputUnZippedFiles\Log_WithHeader.csv
```

And getting excption:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: testData\testInputsFile\testLZInputUnZippedFiles\Log_WithHeader.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

what should i fixed? i want to avoid to copy the file outside from the src.

Answer (score 0):

To access a file named "my.properties" which is inside `src/main/resources/`, you just need to do:

```
File propertiesFile = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("my.properties").getFile());
```

Comment: I am getting error on it - Required: java.io.File Found: java.lang.String

Comment: @Tamar I had missed the `new File()` constructor. See updated answer.